# Como converter uma função baseada em promise para callback em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async, promises, assincronismo, callback

Podemos converter funções assíncronas que trabalham com *callback* para trabalharem com *promises*, como demonstrado nos exemplos abaixo:

`callback`:

```js
const timeInMs = 1_000;

function asyncCallback(timeMs, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(null, timeMs), timeMs);
}

console.log('first');

asyncCallback(timeInMs, (err, result) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error: ', err);

  console.log('last');

  console.log('Time passed: ', result);
});

console.log('second');
```

Mudando para `promise`:

```js
const timeInMs = 1_000;

function asyncCallback(timeMs, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(null, timeMs), timeMs);
}

// função simples para converter callback em promise
function promisify(callback) {
  return function promisified(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const argsArray = [
        ...args,
        function (err, result) {
          if (err) return reject(err);

          resolve(result);
        },
      ];

      callback(...argsArray);
    });
  };
}

// promisificando e convertendo a função asyncCallback
const asyncPromise = promisify(asyncCallback);

console.log('first');

asyncPromise(timeInMs).then((result) => {
  console.log('last');

  console.log('Time passed: ', result);
});

console.log('second');

// usando async/await
(async () => {
  const result = await asyncPromise(timeInMs);

  console.log('[async/await] Time passed: ', result);
})();
```

Repare que foi possível mudar de *callback* para *promise* graças a função customizada `promisify()`.

A pergunta é:

- **Como** converter uma função baseada em *promise* para *callback*, ou seja, fazer o oposto de `promisify()`? Algo como `callbackify()`.

Tem uma função no Node.js chamada [`callbackify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_callbackify_original) do *core module* `util` que faz já faz o caminho inverso:

```js
import { callbackify } from 'util'

const timeInMs = 1_000

function asyncCallback (timeMs, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(null, timeMs), timeMs)
}

function promisify (callback) {
  return function promisified (...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const argsArray = [
        ...args,
        function (err, result) {
          if (err) return reject(err)

          resolve(result)
        },
      ]

      callback(...argsArray)
    })
  }
}

const asyncPromise = promisify(asyncCallback)

const callbackFunction = callbackify(asyncPromise)

callbackFunction(timeInMs, (err, result) => {
  console.log('Time passed: ', result) // Time passed:  1000
})
```

Mas eu quero saber como seria feito uma função **"na mão"** (semelhante à `promisify()`), com passo a passo e com explicação detalhada, porque quero entender a lógica de implementação.

Esta minha dúvida é só uma prova de conceito que gostaria de saber.

Comment: Se você achou algo parecido, fique a vontade para sinalizar como duplicada. Achei que seria um assunto interessante. :D

Comment: Seria algo como `function callbackify(seuPromise, csuccess, cerror) { seuPromise.then(response => { csuccess(response); }).catch(error => { cerror(error) }); }` e o uso assim `callbackify(asyncPromise, (resp) => { console.log(resp); }, error => { console.error(error); })`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é, e aá está a prova de que se álcool e direção não combinam, sono de madrugada e programação também não.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por convenção, o primeiro parâmetro do *callback* é sempre o que indica o erro, se ocorrido. Os demais são os possíveis valores de sucesso.

Como uma promessa só pode resolver um valor por vez, então o *callback* criado a partir de uma `Promise` pode haver, no máximo, dois parâmetros.

Não é nada muito especial. Poderia fazer algo assim:

```
function callbackify(fn) {
  return function (...args) {
    const callback = args.pop();
    
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('Expected a callback, which was not given.');
    }

    Promise.resolve(fn(...args))
      .then((successValue) => callback(null, successValue))
      .catch((errorValue) => callback(errorValue, null));
  };
}
```

Note que a função `callbackify` espera uma função `fn`. Idealmente essa função deve retornar um objeto `Promise`, apesar de que `Promise.resolve` evita casos em que isso não é feito.

Retorna-se uma nova função (que espera um *callback* em seu último argumento, quando invocada). Note que a função retornada é variádica, isto é, espera um número variado de argumentos, que serão repassados à `fn` quando esta for chamada. Exceto o último, o próprio *callback*, removido via `Array.prototype.pop`.

Claro que daria para encher o código acima com mais algumas verificações, mas omiti esse tipo de coisa para a brevidade do código.